# Generate javascript config for various environments

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, deployment

I am serving spa (using `angular.js`) from `asp.net mvc` application. So, all `.js` files are being served from within `Index.html`

There is one .js file which is more like a config file.

```
//environment 1
//var url1 = "protocol : // abc.com /";

//environment 2
//var url1= "protocol : // xyz.com /";
```

**Problem:** Every time I want to deploy this to a environment using any deployment strategy, I need to un-comment the line respective to that environment.

I cannot apply visual studio transformations as this is not a `.config` file. How can I deploy/prepare this `.js` file without manual intervention like commenting/un-commenting.

I am sure there must be some simple concept to solve this problem which I don't know. May be something like generate this file from server side. How can I solve this?

Comment: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html

Comment: Often it is solved by reading settings in web.config, but it sounds like you can't do config transformation...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gulp as task runner. I have recently used in my own work to bundling, minifying and versioning all assets(JS files, css, HTML). [This](http://www.freshconsulting.com/how-to-organize-your-gulp-js-development-builds-for-multiple-environments/) example is very easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

If you use javascript bundling in MVC, you can bundle a different javascript file based on an environment setting in web.config.

For example in a RegisterBundles method:

```
var appBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/app").Include(...);
var environment = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["environmentName"];
appBundle.Include($"~/js/config.{environment}.js");
bundles.Add(appBundle);
```